# php - inserting the values of multiple checkbox selections

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

the site i'll be refering to is

http://www.iaddesignandstudio.com/offline select the quote tab

if a person where to fill out this form and select more than one checkbox in either number 1 or number 3. how would i insert those selected values into a database so that when i retreive the information the user inputed or selected i can see which checkboxes he/she selected?

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242181/inserting-checkbox-values-into-database

Comment: BTW, "1. What is the main purpose of your internet presents ?" Presents should be presence.

Comment: While they ask the same question, this is a lot more general and I think merits keeping around.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your checkboxes to be in one array after the form is submitted by adding `[]` at the end of the `name` attribute like such:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Podcasting Services" /> 
Podcasting Services      
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Local Search" />Local Search
```

When the form is submitted, your `$_POST['services']` variable will be an array containing all checked values. ex:

```
#var_dump($_POST['services']);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "Podcasting Services"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Local Search"
}
```

Then you can do anything you want with that, wether it be sending an email or adding fields to the database using ether `foreach()` or `implode()` to loop through the values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: should i insert it using commas? in one column?  so in this case colservices would contain  Podcasting Services, Local Search ?

Comment: just use implode(', ',$_POST['services']) to get a comma separated list. Note: you will need to check to make sure $_POST['services'] exists or even better is an array already with: if(is_array($_POST['services'])

Answer (score 2):

I would have separate fields in the database for them. Like in question 1, the posted form might submit $_POST['admycomp'] and $_POST['provideresource'] as having been checked. If so, insert a 1 into the database field admycomp or provideresource. That way you have recorded which fields they checked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the values in your database would be to use the SET datatype (eg: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html). This would store each of the checkbox values from a checkbox group in a single column in a storage-efficient way. You would probably need to use implode as mentioned above to create an SQL query to insert your set.