# How to save checkbox value to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following html:

```
<label for="live">Live</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="live" id="live" />
```

How to save `text value of selected = '1'`/ or `text value of unchecked = '0'` to database using SQL INSERT?

Any suggestion much appreciated.

PHP handling the html form (at the moment 'live' is an input):

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('../inc/config.php');

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if($link) {
        echo "DB SUCESS <br />";
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }
    if($db){ echo "TABLE SUCCESS<br />"; }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $live = clean($_POST['live']);
    $content = clean($_POST['content']);


        //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "INSERT INTO news(live, content) VALUES('$live','$content') ";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        //header("location: ../form/register-success.php");
        echo "Succes";      
        exit();
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Comment: If that's all you've got, you've got a long way to go. What PHP code have you got? Have you ***tried*** any of the PHP functions for database interactions? Whats the schema of your database? Are you using standard form submission, or wanting to use AJAX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting checkbox values into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242181/inserting-checkbox-values-into-database)

Comment: @matt yes, sorry.. one sec. DB has a table with column 'live' VARCHART 1 character long. PHP code is a seperate file - no AJAX.

Comment: @hakre - example you have submitted is completely different and involves some loops.

Comment: @Pete: So how far does the code get? What errors do you get? Have you used [`mysql_error()`](http://gr.php.net/mysql_error)?

Comment: @Pete: Well, you should actually first read it as it's highly likely that it includes any single of your problems explained in that linked questions answers. And yeah, learn HTML to actually understand. And then learn some PHP and then learn the MySQL. However, you can continue asking questions about any single problem your run over, then ask back when you get an answer and so on and so forth. You're free to choose, it's your decision.

Comment: @ There is no error. I'm want to replace 'LIVE' input="text" with input="checkbox".

Comment: @hakre - asking question about the problem for which you don't know answer to, IS THE IDEA of this website. Where does it say you have to be advance user of the SUBJECT to ask question about this subject? Some question are dead easy some more complicated. If you feel that my simple (newby) question are to simple for you - you should thick to some kind of ADVANCE forums.

Comment: @Pete: Only posting me a possible duplicate does not mean that I dislike it that you ask your question. Please don't feel offended, you ask the question, others answer and comment it and suggest duplicates and or related posts. That's just it. If you reserve you the right to ask a question, please allow others the right to work with your question. That's how this site does work and the idea is to get together multiple opinions.

Comment: @Pete: [Terrik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956998/how-to-save-checkbox-value-to-mysql-database/6957134#6957134) should do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="live" value="1" />Live<br />
```

^Note the Value "1".  If someone checks the box, it will be a 1, if they don't it will be NULL.  (NOT 0!)

Do an isset on the next page, if it's set, you're good to go, if it's not, just set it to zero.

```
if (!isset($live)) $live = 0;
```

Comment: Should I do that before 'Sanitize' ?

Comment: Nope.  Get your get or post variables and immediately sanatize the hell out of them, always.  You might need to do some checks to make sure it doesn't change the NULL into a string "null" or something, (honestly can't remember how the sanitize functions affect a null, sorry) but be safe and ALWAYS sanitize any user input at all before you do anything else with it.

Comment: Quick one: if `'if (isset($live))'` the value of `$live is 'on'` - not 1. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Only checked HTML checkboxes send values in the response. Use `isset`.

Comment: Checked checkbox = value of '1'?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter. If the variable in the $_POST array is set you already know that it's checked.

Comment: @Pete: See as well this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242181/inserting-checkbox-values-into-database/242215#242215