# How to use checkbox to delete data from database after submit

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

So I am making this website and i got some data in my database. The data is read automatically with php into a table. Every table row also gets automatically a checkbox. Now I want to check the checkbox and then press delete and it deletes the checked data out of the database. Any ideas how?

Here is my code:

```
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Paswoord</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$user['UserName']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$user['Pass']."</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='checked'</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<form method= "POST" action="deleteuser.php">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE USERS">
</form>
```

this is the code in my delete user.php

```
$checked = $_POST['checkbox'];

if($_POST['checkbox'] == "checked"){
echo "SUCCEEEEEEES";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting checkbox values into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242181/inserting-checkbox-values-into-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to be aware of;

- The syntax and proper way of writing the `<form>` tags.
- Use the `<input>` fields inside the `<form>`.
- Pass an array of `checkbox[]` instead of a single `checkbox`.

> Your Code

```
<form method= "POST" action="deleteuser.php">
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Paswoord</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$user['UserName']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$user['Pass']."</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='checked'</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE USERS">
</form>
```

> PHP

Instead of using this;

```
if($_POST['checkbox'] == "checked"){
echo "SUCCEEEEEEES";
}
?>
```

> Use this;

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val)
    {
       echo $val . " this should be deleted";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This did the trick ! Thank you VERY much

Comment: Can i make a connection with my database inside that foreach loop or wil this be bad? Same question for the query

Comment: No, it's better to make the connection in a separate file and save it as `config.php` and then include/require that file like `require('config.php');` in the start of your php.

Comment: Okay, last question. If i know want to delete the database values that are linked to the checkbox? how do i do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell without looking at the code but my wild guess would be to take a value of a checkbox and then use that value to delete the record in your database. something like `$uname = $user['UserName'];  <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='<?php echo $uname; ?>'</td>` and then use the $uname to delete the record in the php.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what I always do :-

Make these changes to your while loop.

```
<?php
$c=0;
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  $c++
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$user['UserName']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$user['Pass']."</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-$c' value='checked'</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='total' value='$c'>";
?>
```

deleteuser.php (Access all the checkboxes here via a for loop)

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['total'];$i++)
{
    if($_POST['checkbox-$i'] == "checked")
    {
        //commands for delete
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If i use your echo "input type='hidden' name='total'... i lose my delete button and it does not work

Comment: I want to make sure that after I check the boxes and press my delete button, the items will be deleted out of my database

Comment: @user5227574 That shouldn't happen, I'm only changing the `name` of the checkbox. Can you upload your file somewhere?

Comment: http://we.tl/99Ox9qbqd4 it's a WeTransfer link so you can download the .zip file! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't download zip files due to security reasons. Upload it on your server.

Comment: I don't have one, i'm using localhost

Comment: Show a screenshot of table produced by HTML.

Comment: WeTransfer should allow you to download it but here is the good old zippy share! http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/9ImPsiF1/file.html Can you download it now?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the name of the checkbox from `checkbox` to `checkbox[]`. Now you get an Array instead a string.
And then set value-attribute to the ID of you row in the table (Primary Key or whatelse you need to delete them)

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$user["UserID"]."'</td>";
```

Now you can iterate them in PHP

```
foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $value){
    // ..Delete FROM ... where userID = $value
}
```

Comment: Does not work. error already in your foreach

Comment: ohh yes ^_^ PHP use `as` then `in`- fix my Artikel

Comment: but you have also one big mistake. you must set the `<input`-Field within the `<Form`-Tag !!
to check the values you got, try this: `var_dump($_POST);`