# How to insert multiple values of checkbox in multiple rows with same id in database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

Here is my html code

```
    <form action="view.php" method="post" id="form">
    <p>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="INCOMETAX" />INCOMETAX</p>

    <p>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="GST" />GST</p>

    <p>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="VAT" />VAT</p>
```

My php code is here

```
if ( isset($_POST['check']) ) {
        $checkbox1=$_POST['check'];  

        $chk = "";  
        foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
        {  
         $chk .= $chk1 .",";

                   $sql = "INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('$chk')";

        }
```

The code is work proper but I want to store value in new row with same id ,rightnow the multiple values from checkbox is stored like INCOMETAX,GST,VAT

how I store INCOMEtax in first row,GST in second row and VAT in third row with same id 1

Comment: Is the id column of your `value` table not a primary key and thus unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a foreach loop in php that will include Insert statement for every checkbox that is selected.

This question was already asked actually. Here is a link
[Inserting checkbox values into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242181/inserting-checkbox-values-into-database)

Also I encourage you to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($_POST['check']) ) { 

    $checkbox1=$_POST['check'];

    $sql = "";  
    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1) {      
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('".$chk1."')");
    }
}
```

this will insert to database everytime instead of generating query

Comment: ERROR  :--------INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('INCOMETAX');INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('GST');Error: INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('INCOMETAX');INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('GST');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO value (service) VALUES ('GST')' at line 1

Comment: @PayalPawar just now i created a table according to your field in the name of value, and I copied your error message and removed those unwanted letters **ERROR :--------** and executed in mysql.. Everything works for me .

Try after replacing this line

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `value` (`service`) VALUES ('".$chk1."')");

That error might have occured because of your table name, because value is a function in mysql . so when you are using as table or field you should use **`** symbol. Let me know it works or not.